# Inconsistent initial and boundary conditions in heat equation

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve the heat equation in 1-D. When I evaluate the following

```
NDSolve[
  {D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], {x, 2}], 
   (D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> 0) == 1, 
   (D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> Pi) == 1, 
   u[0, x] == Cos[2 x] + x}, 
  u[t, x], {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, Pi}][[1]]
```

I get the error

> initial and boundary conditions are inconsistent

but I can't see why. I use version 10.2.0.0

Comment: Mathematica assumes 3 pde's: D[u,t]==... Are you shure about your 2 boundary conditions (which usually have to be of lower order as the pde.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the initial and boundary conditions, or with the answer returned.

Comment: Your bc's match your ic, so that warning is erroneous.  The final result looks good though.

Comment: Sorry my comment was wrong. NDSolve gives only a warning (perhaps pointweise inconsintent?) but the NDSolve result seems to be ok in version 11.0.1!

Comment: To be specific, add e.g. `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 40}}` to `NDSolve` will resolve your problem.

Comment: @ xzczd: sorry your comment was hidden while I posted my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid this warning

```
NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], {x, 2}], (D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> 0) ==1, 
(D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> Pi) == 1, u[0, x] == Cos[2 x] + x}
,u[t, x], {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, Pi},
Method -> {"MethodOfLines","SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
  "MinPoints" -> 35}}] [[1]]
```

if you enforce a smoother spacial grid("MinPoints" > 31).

An approach without refinement is "FiniteElement"  (works only with NeumannValue instead of the two bc D[u[t,x],x]==... )

```
NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t] ==D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] + NeumannValue[1, x == 0 ||x == Pi],
u[0, x] == Cos[2 x] + x}, u , {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, Pi}, 
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t,"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement" }}]
```